# Negative Loss function when using cross_val_score in sklearn/keras. Works when not using k fold

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras

I am trying to implement a model which takes in an array of 167 categorical variables (0 or 1), and outputs an estimated value between 0 and 1. Over 300 datapoints are available.

The model works when using a basic model, below:

```
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Dense(units = 80, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 167))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))

classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 200)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

Output is similar to:

```
Epoch 105/200
253/253 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.5582 - acc: 0.0079         
Epoch 106/200
253/253 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.5583 - acc: 0.0079
```

Unfortunately, when I try to use cross validation, model stops working, and loss function becomes large and negative. Code is below:

```
def build_classifier():
    classifier = Sequential()
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 80, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 167))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
    classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    return classifier
classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn = build_classifier, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = classifier, X=X_train, y=y_train, cv=3,n_jobs=1)
```

Output looks like:

```
Epoch 59/100
168/168 [==============================] - 0s - loss: -1106.9519 - acc: 0.0060        
Epoch 60/100
168/168 [==============================] - 0s - loss: -1106.9519 - acc: 0.0060
```

I have toyed with different parameters, but I cannot seem to find what is causing the issue. Still learning, so any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen if the data is sparse. A lot NaNs and Infs can cause this problem. If you are doing a 3 fold validation, it may be possible that in one of the folds, the data selected doesn't contain enough info. Possible solutions can be:

1. Change the random seed.
2. Increase the data set.